# Is it possible to set UserDefinedTableType column default value?

Tags: t-sql, types

I have created my own TableType, is it possible to set a date column default in order to not call `GetDate()` within every insert?

Comment: I hope you are asking this question for SQL Server.

Comment: If so, as fas as I know we can do it to physical table by adding default constraint to date column. But have no idea about how to do it for table types.

Comment: yes, i've added a tsql tag. i cannot add a contraint as i cannot alter tabletype (or i miss something)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite straightforward, as in case of regular tables, but you can not assign a name to that constraint:

```
CREATE TYPE TestType AS TABLE 
( ID INT,
  CreatedDate DATETIME DEFAULT(GETDATE()) 
)
```